# desktop file not showing up in nautilus 'open with'

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

This file used to work, I reinstalled ubuntu and now it won't work. The python script the desktop file is supposed to run works fine. I have tried placing it in ~/.local/share/applications and /usr/share/applications
I have tried setting it executable as well. But it is not showing up in either `open with` > `other application` or `properties` > `open with`

Here is the desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=vlcwrapy-nix
Icon=vlc
Type=Application
Exec=/home/thekindlyone/projects/vlcwrapy-nix/vlcwrapy-nix.py %f
```

Comment: from @thekindlyone I forgot to set the python file as executable. It works fine now. Funny thing is I had written that instruction in the [readme](https://github.com/thekindlyone/vlcwrapy-nix).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry can't comment (need 50 rep) - your desktop file doesn't contain any MIME information. Try to copy the `MimeType=...` line from vlc's desktop file.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work.

Comment: By the way, your readme instructs to make the _desktop file_ executable. This is plain wrong (and potentially dangerous), only the python script should be executable.

Comment: Damn it. Turns out I suck at writing AND reading readmes. Will change. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the python file as executable. It works fine now. Funny thing is I had written that instruction in the [readme](https://github.com/thekindlyone/vlcwrapy-nix).